# ntpd -q lists no servers

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, ntpd

I am trying to set up ntpd on my servers, so that their clocks are kept in sync. I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-16-04), and everything seems fine until the end. It's now a while later and the output of `timedatectl` looks like:

```
      Local time: Thu 2018-06-14 08:41:32 UTC
  Universal time: Thu 2018-06-14 08:41:32 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2018-06-14 08:41:05
       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

and the output of `ntpq -p` is:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 2.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 3.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

I have configured my AWS security groups so that UDP is open to `0.0.0.0/0` on port 123. All outgoing connections are allowed from these servers anyway.

`nmap -sU -p 123` reports:

```
PORT    STATE         SERVICE
123/udp open|filtered ntp
```

`iptables -L -n -v` reports:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 860K packets, 1119M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1206  140K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 573K packets, 460M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1206  140K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I haven't modified the default ntp config at all.

How can I figure out why ntp isn't updating?

Comment: Any chance your instance has a local firewall that's blocking the NTP packets?

Comment: @MadHatter I don't think so. I'm afraid I don't know how I would check.

Comment: @MadHatter I nmap'ed the port, but the situation is no clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure the `nmap` output is dispositive.  Could we get the output of `iptables -L -n -v` on the server in question?

Comment: @MadHatter Done

Comment: OK, that's not it, then.  You're *absolutely sure* your AWS SG is letting UDP/123 in?  And can you confirm the `nmap` test was done from off-server?

Comment: @MadHatter Yup, done from my local machine. And I've double checked the security group ‍♀️

Comment: No possibility of an [AWS NACL](https://serverfault.com/questions/853540/getting-ntp-to-work-on-aws-without-opening-inbound-port-in-security-group) getting in the way?  It really does look like a firewall issue to me.

Comment: @MadHatter I got through from the linked page to a guide getting set up with `chrony` using Amazon's own service. This seems to work!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, and well done for finding a fix!  I'm not sure what I said really constitutes an answer.  I could write it up if you want, so you can accept it and put the question to bed, or you could just delete this question.  What would you prefer?

Comment: @MadHatter Since it's a problem with a solution, lets not delete it, can you write up as an answer? I'll elaborate it with what I actually did and we can mark as accepted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fairly confident that it isn't a firewall issue.  I have my reservations, but you've followed Amazon's [guide to setting up `chrony`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) with Amazon's servers, and it's working.

An interesting experiment would be to try setting up `ntpd` with those same servers, or to point `chrony` at external servers instead.  That would tell us for sure whether the issue is some kind of hard-to-find firewall blocking NTP to servers which aren't internal to Amazon, or if it really is a chrony vs. ntpd issue.